# If $\ d(x_n,x) $ exist then $\ (x_n) $ must be converge a point in $ X $ ?

Tags: convergence-divergence, metric-spaces

Let $\ (X,d) $  be complete metric space, $\ x \in X $  and $\ (x_n) \subset X $  bounded sequence.

If the real valued sequence {$\ d(x_n,x) $} convgergent then $\ (x_n) $ must be converge a point in $ X $ ?

Is it true? if the answer is yes,  how can i show?

Comment: If $d(x_n,x) \to L>0$ then no. Think about $x$ equal to the origin in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $x_n$ rotating around the unit circle. If $d(x_n,x) \to 0$ then of course $x_n \to x$ and you already assumed $x \in X$. A related natural question would be "must $x_n$ have a convergent subsequence?" In this case the answer is again no; an example would be $f_n=\sin(nx)$ in $L^2(0,\pi),f=0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Let $X=\mathbb R$, $x=0$, and $(x_n) = (-1)^n \left( 1 + \frac 1n \right)$.

Then, although $d(x_n,x)$ is convergent, $(x_n)$ is not.

Comment: Just $(-1)^n$ would've done the job. :)

Comment: Haha you're right :)